# How to cite government news?

Tags: bibtex

I want to cite the following webpage using `bibtex`:
http://www2.news.gov.bc.ca/news_releases_2005-2009/2007for0011-000152-attachment1.htm

It seems I should use `@MISC`, but my problem is that what is the author of this webpage, should I write *British Columbia Ministry of Forests and Range*?

```
@MISC{Brit:moun:2006,
author =     {British Columbia Ministry of Forests and Range},
title =  {Mountain pine beetle: {D}istrict breakdown},
month =  February
publisher =  {Victoria, British Columbia, Backgrounder},
year =   2007,
url =
{http://www2.news.gov.bc.ca/news_releases_2005-2009/2007for0011-000152-attachment1.htm},
}
```

Comment: Given that the author is a "corporate" author and it include the keyword `and` is it better to protect it by enclosing in an additional set of braces, .i.e.,: `author =     {{British Columbia Ministry of Forests and Range}},`